# PHP getdate with timestamp ,how to set timezone?

Tags: php, date

I know that this has been asked but my problem is little different i think..
I get the response from a WCF JSON web service..

```
$reservation->ChIn=substr($reservation->ChIn,6,-10);
```

This extracts the timestamp but wastes the +0300 timezone info.

Then calling `$chi=getdate($reservation->ChIn);`
However that may have a problem because even if i set the timezone in page,is getdate aware of it? Because server knows whether timezone is +02 or 03 because of daylight saving.
Another solution would be to add offset * 60 * 60 to timestamp.

Comment: Does this answer help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/8789182/212940

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set default timezone you can set it in 2 ways:

1. Put the default timezone in your php.ini (will require bounce of apache web server).
2. Put this line on top of your PHP script:

   ```
   date_default_timezone_set(@date_default_timezone_get());
   ```